# jquery .find and append img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load pictures name from a xml object and append to div. I am getting confuse with append typing layout, not able to find where im doing typing mistake.

This is working

```
$("#nn").append("<img id='theImg' src='/pic/jas/pic1.jpg'/>");
```

This not working

```
$("#nn").append("<img id='theImg' src='/pic/jas/'" + customer.find("pic_name") + "/>");
```

My jquery script part is

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
        var pic_infoVar = xml.find("pic_info");

        pic_infoVar.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);
        $("#picDiv").append("<img id='theImg' src='/pic/jas/'" + customer.find("pic_name") + "/>");
        });

        $("#loader").hide();
    }
```

Html Div tag

```
<div id="picDiv">
    LoadPic
</div>
```

Comment: There's a misplaced quote in your second code; should be: `"<img id='theImg' src='/pic/jas/" + customer.find("pic_name") + "'/>"`

Comment: `find` return jquery object, not string. and "pic_name" is a tag ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provded that pic_name is infact an element in an XML data structure (ex: <pic_name>pic1.jpg</pic_name>), the code that will do what you want is:

```
$("#nn").append("<img id='theImg' src='/pic/jas/" + customer.find("pic_name").text() + "'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i used to do

```
document.getElementById('nn').innerHTML +='<img src="'+customer.find(\"pic_name\")+'"/>';
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick reply.. you all are awesome programer.